# Gaelyk - How Can I pass model objects between Controller and View

Tags: google-app-engine, groovy, gaelyk

I am just starting to use Gaelyk.

I was expecting it to behave like Spring MVC; I create my model object in the controller.groovy, and the format the model object in the .gtpl.

In the controller I do this

```
def model = new MyModel()
model.setMyId(2)
```

and in the .gtpl I do this

```
<h1>Test ${model.myId}</h1>
<p>
    Model object is ${model}
</p>
```

However when I run this I get a **MissingPropertyException**

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: model for class: SimpleTemplateScript1
```

In the tutorial examples the model object is shoehorned into an Attribute of **javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest** which IS accessible to the .gtpl.

Is this really the only way pass data between the controller and the template ?
I would feel cleaner if I could avoid polluting the Request (or Response) objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your only option is the request object (as you say).  You set the variables into the request object like:

```
def model = new MyModel()
model.setMyId(2)
request.model = model

forward 'view.gtpl'
```

Then, in `view.gtpl` you do:

```
<h1>Test ${request.model.myId}</h1>
<p>
    Model object is ${request.model}
</p>
```

As `request` is short-lived, I wouldn't say it's polluting the Request object, more utilising it ;-)

And it's miles better than using (for example) the session object

PS:  I realise you probably already know how all this works, as you state that the docs say to use the request object :-/

Comment: As I suspected. Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

adding to the tim_yates response you can wrap your entire gtpl with this:

**controller:**

```
request.model = [myId:123]
```

**view:**

```
<% request.model.with{ %>
...
<p> this is my id: ${myId} </p>
...
<% } %>
```